# Frontal Camera Image Distortion

Tags: android, android-camera

I've developed an application for Android. With camera. And there is very strange behaviour on some devices. The thing is that taken image is very distorted.

Like this
[image: result image]

This issue occures only on some devices (Nexus 4 as example) and only when image is taken with frontal camera ! When image is taken with rear camera everything works great (Even on Nexus 4)

So I have no idea how this can be and what should I do with this. 
Googling gave no results at all. And this is a big problem because I have no Nexus 4, so I can't debug the application on it.

I just found that in AndroidMainfest.xml there is no android.camera.front feature described in uses-feature tag can it be the reason of such strange behaviour ?

Need help ...

Comment: No ... Googling gave no results ... Different tests with Manifest.xml gave no results as well ...

Comment: Searching for the same solution,
maybe this one helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22999869/371749

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem was in "uses-feature" tag in AndroidManifest.xml.
After android.camera.front feature were added everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. In my case adding the permission did not fix it. Could you show me your manifest file or have any idea why this still isn't working in my case?

Comment: To be honest It started working not on all devices. I still have this problem on Galaxy Note. AND I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO WITH THIS. Googling gave no results at all.