# How to capture image size (dimension) 2048x1536 from android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-camera-intent

I want to capture image size 2048x1536 from android camera. How is it possible? Also save in SD Card folder. Can anybody please help me if it is possible.

Comment: Just as an added note: not all devices will be able to support that kind of image size

Comment: This might help you solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865598/android-camera-parameter-setpicturesize-causes-streaked-picture. If the image size isn't supported you could capture in a size with similar dimensions and scale it to the size you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture image from android camera and set Custom dimention (width X height) without deinformation(keep original image qualily)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508445/how-to-capture-image-from-android-camera-and-set-custom-dimention-width-x-heigh)  -- the other question appears to be a restatement of this one.

Comment: no, that is very difference of this.