# Low Quality Image output Camera API

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera, lg

I've developed an app where the user takes a picture, the image is then temporarily written to file to check for network connection, if network is available, upload to server.

I have been testing and it works like a treat.  However, I started to test on a LG Nexus 4 and the image is of very low quality.  The preview is perfect quality, however when it's uploaded and displayed in the app its quality is so low you can't even make out the image.

I have testing on samsung s3 and s4 and images displayed are perfect.  I logged the size of the byte array in the onPictureTaken method and the size by comparison to the value produced by the other two devices is very low.

I have noticed in the log cat I get this:

```
09-22 10:15:13.001     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx111_preview.so: 30
09-22 10:15:13.101     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_ops_init: E
09-22 10:15:13.111     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
09-22 10:15:13.111     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
09-22 10:15:13.121     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ mctl_init_stats_proc_info: snap_max_line_cnt =30096
09-22 10:15:13.131      174-174/? E/QCameraHWI﹕ android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0xb79ae9d8, mStreamDisplay = 0x0xb79a8448
09-22 10:15:13.131      174-174/? D/QCameraHWI﹕ android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview():  start preview now
09-22 10:15:13.131      174-174/? I/QCameraHWI﹕ android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview2():Setting ZSL mode
09-22 10:15:13.131     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_proc_CAMERA_SET_INFORM_STARTPREVIEW
09-22 10:15:13.131     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 1 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 810081 cid = 0
09-22 10:15:13.151     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 3 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 830083 cid = 0
09-22 10:15:13.151     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 4 as : width = 512, height 384, format = 1 inst_handle = 840084 cid = 0
09-22 10:15:13.171     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 3, Op mode 1
09-22 10:15:13.171     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 0 Full size streaming : Disabled
09-22 10:15:13.171     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
09-22 10:15:13.171     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 3, Path: 4
09-22 10:15:13.171     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_update_inst_handles Updated the inst handles as 810081, 830083, 0, 0
09-22 10:15:13.312     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx111_zsl.so: 26
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ camif_client_set_params: camif has associated with obj mask 0x1
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_v2_CAMERA_START_common CAMIF_PARAMS_ADD_OBJ_ID failed -1
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_operation_config: format 3
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=5
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ Invalid ASD Set Params Type
09-22 10:15:13.402     196-4548/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_set_bestshot: Bestshot mode not changed
```

So I'm just asking in the hope if anyone has come across this before?  Or would anyone have any information about it because I'm not sure how to proceed...

thanks

***EDIT***
In order to try to fix this issue I added the following code:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes =  camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
List<Camera.Size> supportedPictureSize = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
Log.i("SUPPORTED SIZES: ", String.valueOf(supportedPreviewSizes.size()));
Log.i("SUPPORTED PICTURE SIZES: ", String.valueOf(supportedPictureSize.size()));
parameters.setPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes.get(0).width, supportedPreviewSizes.get(0).height);
parameters.setPictureSize(supportedPictureSize.get(1).width, supportedPictureSize.get(1).height);
```

As I had thought that an unsupported picture size was being used.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to help. Good that you explained in a comment that you were not using Intent - this was impossible to understand from the original question. Anyways, a wild guess: you choose picture size and/or format that is not supported by the Nexus 4 camera.

Comment: @AlexCohn Sorry I thought that mentioning the Camera Api in the subject automatically ruled out that I was using intents, apologies again for that.  I actually hadn't chosen a size/format at all but while trying to fix this issue I added in code (i've included in my edit above) but it didn't work for me, so I really don't know what to do, I am compressing the images afterwards but it's the byte [] that comes from the onpicturetaken that is the issue as far as I can see!

Comment: So, what is `supportedPictureSize.get(1)` on your device? Is it back camera or front-facing camera?

Comment: that's just the supported picture size..I also have code into to check the cameras and to open camera 0...which is the back camera...so that's all fine...it's incredibly frustrating

Comment: My question was _what was this size_. Maybe, it's simply too small. Maybe, you should choose not `get(1)`, but some other index?

Comment: you asked me "what is supportedPictureSize.get(1) on your device? Is it back camera or front-facing camera?" -  I replied to say supportedPictureSize is just the supported picture size, so it's an array returned from 'camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes()'.  It's not in relation to the camera (whether it's front or back) I have additional code in to check how many cameras and to ensure it's the correct camera that's selected.  I added this code supportedPictureSize.get() as an attempt to fix the already existing problem

Comment: Please see the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652712/getsupportedpicturesize-returns-a-value-which-is-not-actually-supported-by-nex. Nexus 4 had some buggy picture sizes listed, but I am not sure if these did not change on latest SW upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            uri);
                    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

this will helps to you capture high quality image and store in a file pointed by uri.
(if you dont add MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT in intent it will return a low quality image).

Comment: but we can't change Camera App Resolution from our app

Comment: @Nooh I am using the camera api, I'm not using capture intents.

Comment: @praveen yes I know so I'm confused as to why this is happening, when I take the picture and the image preview is shown it looks fine, however, when I check the size of the byte[] from the jpegcallback it's really small by comparison to that of the data captured by the samsung devices

Comment: does anyone have any ideas?